# How to use jquery to loop through DOM element's text and match to the value of a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, dom, momentjs

I am using momentjs to find current hour

let currentHour = moment().format("hA");

I need to loop through the DOM to match the currentHour to the text in the div with the .hour class. If it's a match, I need to apply a css class called "present" to change the styling of that div.

```js
let currentHour = moment().format("hA");
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <!-- hourblocks go here -->
        <div id="hours" class="row time-block">
            <div class="col-md-1 hour">
                9AM
            </div>
            <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
            <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

            <div class="col-md-1 hour">
                10AM
            </div>
            <textarea class="col-md-10 description"> </textarea>
            <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

            <div class="col-md-1 hour">
                11AM
            </div>
            <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
            <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

            <div class="col-md-1 hour">
                12PM
            </div>
            <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
            <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

            <div class="col-md-1 hour">
                1PM
            </div>
            <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
            <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

            <div class="col-md-1 hour">
                2PM
            </div>
            <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
            <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

            <div class="col-md-1 hour">
                3PM
            </div>
            <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
            <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

            <div class="col-md-1 hour">
                4PM
            </div>
            <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
            <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

            <div class="col-md-1 hour">
                5PM
            </div>
            <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
            <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

 </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: jQuery [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/), jQuery [`.text`](https://api.jquery.com/text/), and jQuery [`.addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/#addClass-className). Look at these.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to loop in the traditional sense (`for` / `.each`) as you can let jquery selector find the info you need:

```
$(":contains(" + value + ")")
```

in your case that's

```
$(".hour:contains(" + currentHour + ")")
```

combine with `.addClass("present")` gives:

```js
let currentHour = moment().format("hA");
$(".hour:contains(" + currentHour + ")").addClass("present");
```

```css
.present{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <!-- hourblocks go here -->
  <div id="hours" class="row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      7AM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      8AM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      9AM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      10AM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"> </textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      11AM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      12PM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      1PM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      2PM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      3PM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      4PM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      5PM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

  </div>
</div>
```

---

To address the relevant issues in the comment

> contains matches partial matches

`contains()` is essentially:  text == "*" + value + "*" - instead, use `.filter()`.

> change the .description

is just a case of locating the description after

Updated:

```js
let currentHour = moment().format("hA");

$(".hour").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() === currentHour;
  })
  .nextAll(".description")
  .first()
  .addClass("present");
  
// don't use `.next(".description")` just `.next()` if it will always be the very next element
```

```css
.present {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <!-- hourblocks go here -->
  <div id="hours" class="row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      7AM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      8AM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      9AM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      10AM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"> </textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      11AM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      12PM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      1PM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      2PM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      3PM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      4PM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      5PM
    </div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description"></textarea>
    <button class="col-md-1 saveBtn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried this solution and there are two issues with this. One, using contain wrongly highlights 11AM instead of 1AM (the current time, I know it doesn't exist, but still), and two, I don't think I specified initially, but the div I need to change the styling on is the .description class not the .hour class. Thanks for the quick response!